Study of the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mbox{tg}{\left(\frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+3}\right)}$
I would like to ask, if possible, help with the convergence study of such a series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mbox{tg}{\left(\frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+3}\right)}$$
My idea is this; with the convergence criterion, by calculating the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}$  of the argument of the series which is equal to zero i can see that it can converge, the argument of the tangent goes as $\frac{1}{n}$ and consequently I can rewrite the series as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mbox{tg}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
Given that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0 \to y=\frac{1}{n} $$
$$\lim_{y\to 0}{tg(y)} \sim y $$
where $\sim$ is to be understood as a first-order Taylor, i.e. my series goes like $\frac{1}{n}$
which is the harmonic series I know diverges, so the series diverges.
Is this a ‘correct’ process? If yes, are there others to arrive at the answer?
I know it diverges because Wolfram suggests it to me, but he does not show the process.
Thank you, this is already the second time I've seen this series, with different terms but no solution, and I don't know how to solve it myself.

You can also use the inequality $\tan x\ge x$:
$$\tan\left(\frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+3}\right)\ge \frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+3}=\frac n{n^2+5n+6}:=a_n $$
And $\sum a_n$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series
.
